# Not able to integrate firebase storage to my android app

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0, firebase-storage

I have been trying to integrate **firebase** storage to my Android app by following **[this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)** link.

But when I try to sync my gradle files it gives me following errors

> Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: **com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.2**
>
> Error:Failed to resolve: **com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2**

Comment: i think you put dependency in Project Gradle
where have you put this dependency Project or Moudle

Answer (score 1):

There are two different gradle files.

First one is Project Level gradle, build.gradle(Project:)

Here, you add below line dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Second is Module Level gradle, build.gradle(Module:app)

Here, you `add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end your file and

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
```

inside dependencies.

Make sure you have followed this way.

Comment: Have exactly done the same but with no luck. Just wanted to know if there is any dependency on specific version of google repository that comes with android SDK extras?